# Compiling source files with identical filenames but with different paths

Tags: android, c++, qt, qmake

I'm "porting"(сloser to the truth) application from iOS to Android and could not even build. The problem is on linking stage where same .o files are in use, but obviously just one exists in the target directory:

> Makefile.Test4b:12284: warning: ignoring old commands for target
>   `Session.o'
>   /usr/local/Caskroom/android-ndk/19/android-ndk-r19/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++
>   -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -target aarch64-none-linux-android -gcc-toolchain /usr/local/Caskroom/android-ndk/19/android-ndk-r19/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
>   -fno-limit-debug-info -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a --sysroot=/usr/local/Caskroom/android-ndk/19/android-ndk-r19/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/
>   -Wl,-soname,libqueen-test4b.so -Wl,-rpath=/Applications/Qt/5.12.4/android_arm64_v8a/lib -Wl,-rpath-link=/Applications/Qt/5.12.4/android_arm64_v8a/lib -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -o libtest4b.so ... **Session.o** ... **Session.o** ...

Source files are in different directories and in different c++ namespaces.

This is how xcodebuild deal with it:

> CompileC .xcode/test4b.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test4b.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Session-**804CCC700882D686**.o
>   /Users/danilabagroff/test4b/Model/Application/Session.cpp normal
>   x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

How to add a suffix like xcodebuild but with (q)make or how to put each object file in a different directory?

ps. Don't want to rename source files ;)

Comment: Did You try to separate into different static libs? Was it also previously 1 project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CONFIG += object_parallel_to_source
```

did the trick.